# Minimal normal subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $N$ be a minimal normal subgroup of a group $G$ and suppose $T$ is a minimal normal subgroup of $N$. Since $N \triangleleft G$, we have that $g^{-1}Tg \subseteq N$, for all $g \in G$.

How does this imply that $g^{-1}Tg$ is a minimal normal subgroup of $N$, for all $g \in G$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Ad}{Ad}$
Let $\alpha$ be any automorphism of $N$.  Then $\alpha(T)$ is a minimal normal subgroup of $N$.  In particular this is true for $\alpha = \Ad(g)$ for $g \in G$